# How to map a Map<Calendar,Boolean> with jpa/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

i've got 2 tables:

Seat(roomID,seatID,...)
SeatState(roomID,seatID,date,state)

i wanna create a seat class and i would like this class to have a Map attribute. does somebody know how to map this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate supports using 'Map's as collections. If you are using hbm.xml files, you can use the <map> tag for this purpose. Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html for a reference. Also Hibernate supports mapping Calendar fields to TIMESTAMP fields.

So if you are using XML, it should be something like

```
<map name="booking" table="BOOKING">
    <key column="BOOKING_ID"/>
    <map-key column="BOOKING_DATE" type="calendar"/>
    <element column="IS_BOOKED" type="boolean"/>
 </map>
```

Likewise, JPA / Hibernate Annotation alternatives also exist. You need to use @Embeddable to get this done. See http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html for an example.